# Script to work on certain sheetname.... .getSheetByName('Sheet 1'); didn't work. for multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am working with this script:

```
 /**  * Automatically sorts the 1st column (not the header row)
 Ascending.  */ function onEdit(event){   var sheet =
 event.source.getActiveSheet();   var editedCell =
 sheet.getActiveCell();

   var columnToSortBy = 3;   var tableRange = "A2:T99"; // What to
 sort.

   if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
     var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
     ran

ge.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );   }
```

I need it to only run on Sheet 2, Sheet 3, Sheet 4, and not all sheet in the workbook. I tried doing several variation of `getsheets` that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the current sheet is obtained by `sheet.getSheetName()`. 
You want to make sure that this name is one of "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3", "Sheet 4". A concise way to express this condition is to have an array `sheetList` with the names that need to be sorted, and check whether the name of the active sheet is on the list. The method `indexOf` does this check: it returns -1 if the name is **not** on the list.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheetList = ["Sheet 2", "Sheet 3", "Sheet 4"];
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheetList.indexOf(sheet.getSheetName()) != -1) {
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var columnToSortBy = 3;   
    var tableRange = "A2:T99";      
    if (editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy) {   
      var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
      range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this line returns a syntax error  " if (sheetList.indexOf(sheet.getSheetName())) != -1) {